# My app's main screen in Xcode 7 has disappeared

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode7

This is crazy. It's the first time it happens. When I click my project icon something like the first image should appear, with general tab, capabilities, resource tag, info... etc

[image]

But I've tried everything and I'm only getting this screen:

[image]

As you can see there is only two tabs. Can anyone help me to recover the missing tabs please?? Many thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are on the Project view rather then the Target view.
Press on the yuApp button on the top left corner and select the yuApp from the Targets section.

Comment: Yeah, just keep that side bar open and you'll avoid that next time

Answer (score 1):

Select a **Target** and the tabs will appear.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Click on this. (Link to image I had in my drive)

[Click on drop down menu and select your project](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B5j_BdtRjSyAcmsxZEFKZFFLOGM)